# Get indexes of maximum values in array

Tags: c++, stl

I need to get indexes of max values in an array.
Something like `std::max_element`. But if there are several entries with the same max values
I need to get all indexes, not only the first one.
How can I do it, using STL?

Comment: Closed while answering. Look at example here https://ideone.com/9fQA97

Comment: See if this helps https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TbbW6K

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use `std::max_element` to do the initial work, but for the rest of the work you may need to employ `std::find` or something similar. Could look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  const auto vec = std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2});
  
  // Part 1: Find the maximum.
  const auto max = std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  if (max == vec.end())
  {
    // Not required here, but in the general case an empty vector could occur.
    std::cout << "Vector is empty." << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  std::cout << "Maximum is " << *max << "." << std::endl;

  // Part 2: Find all indices of elements equal to the maximum.
  auto iterator = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *max);
  while (iterator != vec.end())
  {
    std::cout << "found maximum at index " << std::distance(vec.begin(), iterator)
              << std::endl;
    ++iterator;
    iterator = std::find(iterator, vec.end(), *max);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output in that case would be:

```
Maximum is 3.
found maximum at index 2
found maximum at index 4
found maximum at index 6
```

You can also use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`, if you are having a container that always has the same amount of elements.